# Unable to connect development server. Ensure that the packager server is running

Tags: android, react-native

I am a starter of React-native tho I am having trouble with debugging. Program is successfully installing apk to emulator but can not render the component. Whenever I double press 'R' (I am on windows) it throws following error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`cd YourProject
react-native run-android
react-native start`